# Is there a way to search curly braces in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How can I search for empty curly braces in kibana ?

e.g.

I have some messages in elasticsearch:

```
test1 1235512 {"command":"session","params":{}} test1
test2 1235512 {"command":"session","params":{"k1": "p1"}} test2
test3 1235512 {"command":"session","params":{"k2": "p2"}} test3 df
test4 1235512 {"command":"session","params":{}} test4 some more text
```

I need to find all documents where exists empty curly braces {}. For this case in response I want to get test1 and test4 documents. Or if someone can give the elasticsearch request it also can be very helpful )

Comment: It depends on the mappings you are using to store this data in `kibana`.  If you can add this mapping info, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna **search on kibana**, why not simply try this?

works for me.

[image]